# How does this syntax work? {fn CurDate()} or {fn Now()} etc

Tags: sql-server, functions

Recently I've been looking through some fairly old stored procedures that were written for SQL Server 2005, and I've noticed something that I don't understand.  It appears to be some type of function call.

A sample:

```
SELECT o.name, o.type_desc, o.create_date
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.create_date < {fn Now()} -1;
```

This will display all rows from `sys.objects` that have a `create_date` prior to 24 hours ago.

If I display the execution plan for this query, I see that `{fn Now()}` is replaced with `getdate()` by the Database Engine:

```
SELECT [o].[name],[o].[type_desc],[o].[create_date] 
FROM [sys].[objects] [o] 
WHERE [o].[create_date]<(getdate()-@1)
```

Clearly, using `{fn Now()}` is far more obtuse than `GetDate()`.  I for one will avoid this syntax like the plague since it is undocumented.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's ODBC escape syntax, and the engine knows what its own implementation is, and swaps it out, as you've seen in the execution plan. There are also other things, such as:

```
SELECT {fn curdate()},
       {ts '2016-05-24 15:19:36'}, -- not vulnerable to SET LANGUAGE!
       {guid 'D08891B4-BC25-4C7C-BAEF-3B756055AC6E'};
```

See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/odbc-scalar-functions-transact-sql), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/date-time-and-timestamp-escape-sequences), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/guid-escape-sequences), and most importantly [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/odbc-escape-sequences). But please don't investigate and learn about this syntax; IMHO you should use the native syntax for the most part and pretend you've never heard of this stuff.

I also strongly recommend against the `getdate()-1` shorthand, too, particularly if you're going back and updating old code. Be explicit and use `DATEADD`, since the implicit shorthand does not work with new types. For example, try:

```
DECLARE @d DATE = GETDATE();
SELECT @d - 1;
```

Result:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   
> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

While you're in there, may as well add the semi-colons, too if you really want to protect your code 10 years into the future.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I keep fighting the good fight regarding the lack of semi-colon statement terminators.  It's been almost 10 years since this answer was posted, and I wonder if MS is *ever* going to *actually* enforce it.